# proftpd mod_exec in conjuncion with <IfUser>

Tags: configuration, proftpd

Is there a way to enable the module 'mod_exec' only with a certain proftdp user?

I've compiled proftp with --with-modules=mod_exec:mod_ifsession and then configured in this way...

```
<IfModule mod_exec.c>
    <IfUser stefano>
        ExecEngine              on
        ExecLog                 /opt/proftpd-master/logs/proftpd.semics.mod_exec.log
        ExecOptions             logStderr logStdout
        ExecBeforeCommand       STOR,RETR       /path/to/handler.sh EVENT=BeforeCommand FILE='%f'
        ExecOnCommand           STOR,RETR       /path/to/handler.sh EVENT=OnCommand     FILE='%f'
    </IfUser>
</IfModule>
```

or this:

```
<IfUser stefano>
    <IfModule mod_exec.c>
        ExecEngine              on
        ExecLog                 /opt/proftpd-master/logs/proftpd.semics.mod_exec.log
        ExecOptions             logStderr logStdout
        ExecBeforeCommand       STOR,RETR       /path/to/handler.sh EVENT=BeforeCommand FILE='%f'
        ExecOnCommand           STOR,RETR       /path/to/handler.sh EVENT=OnCommand     FILE='%f'
    </IfModule>
</IfUser>
```

without success. Seems that mod_exec works only if configured outside the  conditional statement.

My goal is to enable mod_exec only for user 'stefano' and/or to have several mod_exec configuration accordingly with each user configured.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_exec.c must be enabled by default and then inside it is possible to configure different actions for different users:

```
<IfModule mod_exec.c>
    ExecEngine on
    ExecLog /opt/proftpd-master/logs/proftpd_mod_exec.log
    ExecOptions logStderr logStdout

    <IfUser stefano>
        ExecBeforeCommand STOR,RETR /path/to/script.sh EVENT=BeforeCommand FILE='%f'
        ExecOnCommand STOR,RETR /path/to/script.sh EVENT=OnCommand FILE='%f'
    </IfUser>
</IfModule>
```

Thanks to TJ Saunders. I hope this helps.